# I can't properly download seqinr to open fasta files

Tags: r, import, package, bioinformatics, cran

I am trying to download seqinr for a bioinformatics project.

I went on the CRAN website.  I tried downloading the file from the link and it was difficult.

I tried using the install command, followed by the library command to import it:

```
    install.packages("seqinr", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")

    library(seqinr)
```

I got the following error message:

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'ade4'
* removing 'C:/Users/geniu/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/ade4'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ade4’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'ade4', 'segmented' are not available for package 'seqinr'
* removing 'C:/Users/geniu/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/seqinr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘seqinr’ had non-zero exit status
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or a better way to download this?

Comment: What happens when you try `install.packages(c("ade4","segmented"))`?

Comment: If you are not going to read the packageDescription file then you will often need to address dependencies by trial and error. Always address the first error in a series of error messages when using this strategy. Lather, rinse, repeat, until done